# Локальные переменные jQuery

Tags: jquery

В такой записи обе функции будут "видеть" только свои переменные, если есть две и т.д. одинаковые переменные по названию, или же нет?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('input[data-size]').change(function() {
  var shed     = $('#size1:checked');
  var lumber   = $('#size2:checked');
  var country  = $('#size3:checked');
  var brick    = $('#size4:checked');
  var carriage = $('#size5:checked');
 });

 $('input[data-type]').change(function() {
  var shed     = $('#type1:checked');
  var lumber   = $('#type2:checked');
  var country  = $('#type3:checked');
  var brick    = $('#type4:checked');
  var carriage = $('#type5:checked');
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Да, будут видеть только свои переменные.

Answer (score 0):

при использовании ключевого слова [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) переменная объявляется на уровне функции и не видна извне.

В данном случае в обработчики передаются *две разные* функции, *внутри* которых создаются переменные.

Так как все переменные объявлены *внутри* функций, она не видны снаружи и, следовательно, не пересекаются между собой.